# Как лучше всего сверстать «забор» на бэкграунде?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, каков лучший способ сверстать [подобный «забор»](http://f1.s.qip.ru/hjWejzkg.png).

Основные моменты (если понадобятся):

1. Над забором просто однотонный бэкграунд
2. Под забором — паттерн (т.е. бэкграунд через `background-image` задается)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать отдельный слой, у макета забора найти повторяющуюся часть, обрезать и повторять через repeat-x.

Если не так, то лучше изложите свои "Основные моменты" на jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы разбил на слои: зелёный фон с забором, и каждая из этих полупрозрачных форм поверх, с разными ширинами, чтобы они накладывались друг на друга неповторяясь.

```css
#zabor{
 background-image: 
  url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/multibg/bg-a.png), 
  url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/multibg/bg-b.png), 
  url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/multibg/bg-c.png), 
  url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/multibg/bg1.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="zabor"></div>
```